# Removing axes margins in 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, margins, matplotlib-3d

I spent last few days trying to find a way to remove tiny margins from axes in a 3D plot. I tried `ax.margins(0)` and `ax.autoscale_view('tight')` and other approaches, but these small margins are still there. In particular, I don't like that the bar histograms are elevated, i.e., their bottom is not at the zero level -- see example image.

[image: unwanted margins on all axes]

In gnuplot, I would use "set xyplane at 0". In matplotlib, since there are margins on every axis on both sides, it would be great to be able to control each of them.

**Edit:** 
HYRY's solution below works well, but the 'X' axis gets a grid line drawn over it at Y=0:

[image: strange axis]

Comment: It would really help if you could add the code you use to make the plot, so we have a starting point. Then it's easier for people to copy-paste the code, and thereafter find a solution for this particular problem.

Comment: Lots of sample code [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) ("Bar plots" example is similar to my case above).

Comment: I'll note that this is a confirmed bug, and you can track the progress of the ticket here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18052

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is not property or method that can modify this margins. You need to patch the source code. Here is an example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
###patch start###
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axis3d import Axis
if not hasattr(Axis, "_get_coord_info_old"):
    def _get_coord_info_new(self, renderer):
        mins, maxs, centers, deltas, tc, highs = self._get_coord_info_old(renderer)
        mins += deltas / 4
        maxs -= deltas / 4
        return mins, maxs, centers, deltas, tc, highs
    Axis._get_coord_info_old = Axis._get_coord_info  
    Axis._get_coord_info = _get_coord_info_new
###patch end###

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for c, z in zip(['r', 'g', 'b', 'y'], [30, 20, 10, 0]):
    xs = np.arange(20)
    ys = np.random.rand(20)

    # You can provide either a single color or an array. To demonstrate this,
    # the first bar of each set will be colored cyan.
    cs = [c] * len(xs)
    cs[0] = 'c'
    ax.bar(xs, ys, zs=z, zdir='y', color=cs, alpha=0.8)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

The result is:

[image]

**Edit**

To change the color of the grid lines:

```
for axis in (ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis, ax.zaxis):
    axis._axinfo['grid']['color']  = 0.7, 1.0, 0.7, 1.0
```

**Edit2**

Set X & Y lim:

```
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 31)
ax.set_xlim3d(-1, 21)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked... (1) if I change `for c, z in zip(['r', 'g', 'b', 'y'], [30, 20, 10, 2])`, why the 'X' axis gets a thick dashed line style? (2) How to change colors of grid lines? `ax.grid(color='blue')` does not work.

Comment: @dolphin, can you post the result of (1)? For (2), the color can't be modified by some API, I added the code that changed the hidden _axinfo dict.

Comment: Thanks for (2)! It's a shame that the complexity and flexibility of matplotlib results in so many "hacks" that need to be individually searched for, and the intuitive solutions sometimes work, sometimes not. Regarding (1), I could not post an image in a comment so I pasted a piece of code hoping that you can reproduce it :-) Now I added another image as an Edit in the original question.

Comment: @dolphin, (1) is because the axis line is overlaped with grid line, you can call `ax.set_ylim3d()` to change the Y-axis range to avoid this.

Comment: Indeed. I considered it a bug because this was the only axis overdrawn by the grid, but maybe it is designed/expected to be that way... thank you!

Comment: @HYRY you are the best!  This was plaguing me in a recent plotting project and your fix works flawlessly.  Perhaps you can point me to a patch or solution for how to draw thicker ticks in mplot3D?

Comment: @HYRY thank you! Your patch works perfectly! :) I wonder why this isn't the standard behavior. Do you happen to know why? :)

Comment: Why isn't this hack part of axes3D functionality? It seems to me as if this is "essential" for 3d plots. In my case, I have a bunch of lines ending on the "right wall", but because of the padding, it's hard to gauge whether they end above or below a certain value. One has to visually and mentally do the projection of the axes grid "inward", so to "meet" the actual plot. It's quite disappointing that all the `margins`, `set_xlim` and whatnot functionalities do not cover this (imho big) (de)fault behavior.

Comment: @HYRY I want to use your monkey patching safely, i.e. not to affect the following uses unrelated to this call using a `with` statement, but I don't not how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I had to tweak the accepted solution slightly, because in my case the x and y axes (but not the z) had an additional margin, which, by printing `mins, maxs, deltas`, turned out to be `deltas * 6.0/11`. Here is the updated patch that worked well in my case.

```
###patch start###
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axis3d import Axis
def _get_coord_info_new(self, renderer):
    mins, maxs, cs, deltas, tc, highs = self._get_coord_info_old(renderer)
    correction = deltas * [1.0/4 + 6.0/11,
                           1.0/4 + 6.0/11,
                           1.0/4]
    mins += correction
    maxs -= correction
    return mins, maxs, cs, deltas, tc, highs
if not hasattr(Axis, "_get_coord_info_old"):
    Axis._get_coord_info_old = Axis._get_coord_info  
Axis._get_coord_info = _get_coord_info_new
###patch end###
```

(I've also changed the patching logic around a bit, so that editing the function and reloading its module now works as expected in Jupyter.)

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed and will be released in the upcoming Matplotlib v3.9.0, so that manually setting 3D axis limits will now set the limits exactly without extra padding (see [pull request #25272](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/25272)).

If you prefer the original behavior, then setting the following config will change it back: `plt.rcParams['axes3d.automargin'] = True`.

Comment: This is great news, thanks! So it is also possible to call e.g. `ax.set_zlim(0, 0.8)` to get rid of the "z" padded limit?

Comment: It will be, yes!