# Python - Axis limit in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've created a figure with this

```
  fig8 = plt.figure()
  ax8 = fig8.gca(projection = '3d')
  ax8.set_xlim(0,0.8)
```

It gives me this

[image]

My problem is I really need the limit of axis x to be exactly 0.8. It seems that matplotlib always make the axis a little bit longer than the limits that we've set. Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing axes margins in 3D plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488182/removing-axes-margins-in-3d-plot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be hard-coded:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axis3d.py#L178

If you replace this line by:

```
deltas = 0*(maxs - mins) / 12.
```

you get the desired output but labels are now weirdly positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Nicolas Rougier for the suggestion

to fix the positions of the labels, instead of changing that line. I kept it and change the two lines below

```
deltas = (maxs - mins) / 12.
mins = mins
maxs = maxs
```

It works!!!!