# Matplotlib center plot_surface on axis area

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, surface

I am trying to create a 3d surface plot but the result is not aligned to the origin:
[image]

You can easily see on the Z-projection that it's a little off on the X and Y axes. My data is a matrix where the first two columns are my X's and Y's and the 3rd column is my Z. This is how I compute the values:

```
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
indices = np.digitize(data[:, :2], bins, right=True)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(bins, bins, indexing='ij')
Q = np.zeros_like(X)
C = np.zeros_like(X)
d = data[:, 2]
for idx in range(0, len(indices)):
    (i,j) = indices[idx]
    Q[i, j] += d[idx]
    C[i, j] += 1
C[C == 0] = 1 # avoid division by zero errors
Q /= C
return (X, Y, Q, C)
```

Plotting code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim3d(-0.5, 1)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 1.5)
ax.set_zlim3d(-1.5, 1)
Q = ndi.gaussian_filter(Q, sigma=10)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Q, cmap=cm.coolwarm, lw=lw, rstride=rs, cstride=cs, alpha=a, antialiased=True)
ax.contourf(X, Y, Q, zdir='z', offset=-1.5, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.contourf(X, Y, Q, zdir='x', offset=-0.5, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.contourf(X, Y, Q, zdir='y', offset=+1.5, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
```

My question is, am I missing any calculation to ensure the surface is aligned to the origin? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surface **is** aligned to the origin. But the origin is "hanging in the air". Or in other words, the bottom pane is slightly (~0.05 units) below the contourf plot, which makes it **appear** as if the plot was misaligned.

You may want to look at this question: [Removing axes margins in 3D plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488182/removing-axes-margins-in-3d-plot) use one of the two answers to have the panes aligned properly.