# Matplotlib: Axes3D axis limit is not properly working! How to remove extra offset from bounding ticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, axes

I'm trying to plot 3d bars using `bar3d` and `Axes3D` of *matplotlib* and limiting the z-axis range to [0,1], but `.set_zlim3d(0,1)` method is not properly working and there is extra offset relative to bounding ticks. These extra offsets are shown by two-headed purple arrows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = Axes3D(fig, azim=65, elev=30)
ax.set_zlim3d(0,1)
```

**Result**:
[image]

### My Question:

**How to remove the extra offsets from bounding ticks, i.e. `0.0` and `1.0`?**

(one may say try: `ax.set_zlim3d(0.0000001, 0.9999999)` which yields in loosing `0.0` and `1.0` ticks)

Comment: After `ax.set_zlim3d(0.0000001,1)`, have you tried specifying ticks manually?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan Tnx, yes I knew I could solve the problem by doing these kind of tricks (for example setting the tick of `0.0000001` to `'0.0'`). I was interested if there exists an easier and a more general way of doing this.

Comment: A more general way you say? I believe that would be finding a library that is built to be pixel-perfect. Or do you believe matplotlib contains a function `make_everything_pixel_perfect()`? In that case, it is very safe to assume that would be the default behavior, which it is not.

Comment: In a 2d plot this solution is to set the margin to 0. In a 3d plot, there is x, y , and z margin `ax.set(xmargin=0, ymargin=0, zmargin=0)`, but it doesn't seem to allow for completely removing the margin. Maybe this [Removing axes margins in 3D plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16488182/7758804)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Tnx, this solved the extra (negative) offset from `0.0`, but positive offset from `1.0` still is there.

Comment: Here is (I think) the [related issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18052) on matplotlib's github, perhaps you'd like to also contribute to the discussion there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing axes margins in 3D plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488182/removing-axes-margins-in-3d-plot)